# Generate multiple checkboxes from Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jsfiddle will help explain things better than I ever can >< http://jsfiddle.net/L65QD/17/

I've got two select boxes, when you select something from the first select it enables the second. I have quite a few arrays that I'm using as sort of a fake database.

What I need to happen is that depending on what is selected in profile_select it needs to generate checkboxes for every PRIVILEGE_CODE it has, however the checkboxes must be generated with SEC_PRIVILEGES.Name next to them instead of the actual PRIVILEGE_CODE and they must be generated in the correct DIV. Since it's so hard to explain I made a JSFiddle which just about summarizes it http://jsfiddle.net/L65QD/17/

If my instructions aren't clear:

1. Depending on what profile is selected in the PROFILE_SELECTION
2. Needs to generate some checkboxes based on what PRIVILEGE_PROFILES.PRIVILEGE_CODES it has
3. However the checkboxes must have the name from SEC_PRIVILEGES next to them instead of the code, so PRIVILEGE_CODES = Unique_Code
4. Checkboxes are generated in either the DA div or the MR div based on what Group_Code they have in SEC_PRIVILEGES (this bit really confuses me, can you make it so a DIV ID can be equal to something from an array?) However to generate them in DA or MR it can't really be an IF because my fiddle is just an example and I'd actually have about 30 different codes so I couldn't do 30 IF statements.

This is the method I was experimenting with but it doesn't really make sense and is probably not even close to being on the right lines:

```
   $(document).on('change', '#select_profile', function () {
    var Select = $("#select_profile option:selected").text();
    $("#apps").html;
    for (var i = 0; i < SEC_Privileges.length; i++) {
        if (SEC_Privileges[i].Unique_Code == //something?) {
            $('#DA').html("<b>lol</b>");

        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that's pretty simple:

- **Correct this fatal error:** Array literals are written in square bracket notation (`[]`, not `()`). When you log the `PRIVILEGE_PROFILE[0].PRIVILEGE_CODE` you'll see only the first code is logged as the key's value.
- Building the function: Consider what you need:

  - When a user changes company, all checkboxes must be reset
  - When a user changes profile, all checkboxes must be reset, then changed accordingly
  - When 'None' is selected in either dropdown, all checkboxes must be reset

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/L65QD/19/

Some conventions:

- Please choose one naming convention and stick with it. The more common ones are **lowercase_underscore** or **CamelCase**. You can opt for uppercase, but don't mix them (easier readability). I've had several errors just because I wrote the names incorrectly.
- Declare your variables at the start of your function, assign them further on.

Also want to add that if I were to have control over the object's structure, I would probably opt for a more hierarchical tree/ JSON-like structure, eg instead of your current object, do:

```
var SEC_Privileges = {
    'DA': {
       'name': 'Dispatch App',
       'accesses': {
           'DAAccess': 'Access',
           'DASuper': 'Supervisor'
       }
    },
    'MR': {
       'name': 'MyRoster', 
       'accesses': {
           'MRAccess': 'Access',
           'MRSuper': 'Supervisor'
       }
    }
}
```

Because the object keys are themselves values, you can use them to build your UI, eg to get the full name of your `MRAccess` you could do something like `SEC_Privileges.MR.name + SEC_Privileges.MR.accesses.MRAccess` to get `MyRoster Access`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot buddy :) I'll keep your tips in mind, I'll go ahead and fix all my naming conventions and make it more clearer :3

However there's one tiny thing in your code, next to the checkboxes it says the actual Privileges name when I was hoping to get it to say SEC_PRIVILEGES.Name so for example instead of MRSuper it would be "MyRoster Supervisor" ^^ what needs to be changed? :)

Comment: oop, I just seen the last bit

Comment: @Shaun, find the line `label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SEC_Privileges[i].Unique_Code));` at the end of the function & replace `Unique_Code` with `Name` :)

Answer (score 2):

There is different ways to approach this but the amount of Privileges would always be the same?. Depending on what your SEC_privileges is if its JSON array then you could loop through that array and access the code and the description. You would then want to validate the selected privileges again the whole set and say something like:

```
var array = ('one','two','three');

if($.inArray(SEC_privileges[i].Unique_code, array))
{
$('#DA').html("<input type='checkbox' id='"+i+"' value='"+SEC_privileges[i].Unique_code+"' checked/>"+SEC_privileges[i].Unique_desc);
}
else
{
 $('#DA').html("<input type='checkbox' id='"+i+"' value='"+SEC_privileges[i].Unique_code+"'/>"+SEC_privileges[i].Unique_desc);
}
```

A ticked value is done by adding the word checked as part of the html input object. Like illustrated above

Comment: The amount of privileges would change, it just happens there's a few because I wanted to make it a simple Fiddle.

Comment: What I forgot to clear up is that it can't have an IF like appear in #DA or #MR because there would actually be about 30 different codes, so I couldn't do 30 if statements

Comment: You don't need 30 if statements because its an array so just loop through the array. How are you getting the privileges that is assigned to each profile. If its in json format then you can access it with methods and values. you could even put the div name in an array and output it to minimize the code even more.

Comment: I mean where it says $('#DA').html in your method, does that mean I'd have to create multiple If's like in yours with different DIV id's in the statements? Sorry if I'm sounding stupid here.

Comment: you would have an if statement above the other if statements and just assign the div name to a var for example you would then just use the var instead of $('#DA') would become $(mydivvar). You would default the mydivvar like var mydivvar = '#DA'; and in your if statement just over assign it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kevsharp81/968vf/19/ ive had a play with your code. Any problems please let me know.

Comment: That's kind of what I wanted however I wanted it to only generate the checkboxes based on what privileges they had and not generate the 4 checkboxes then depending what privileges they have, have them unticked/unticked. They should always be checked when generated :) What needs to be changed? ^^

I really appreciate the help as well

Comment: Oh, the other guy fixed it but I really appreciate your help :) I'll give you some upvotes for karma for all your troubles c: